# How to set a timeout to a SOAP call

Tags: java, soap, timeout

I need to set a timeout to a SOAP call using javax.xml.soap over HTTPS
However I don't know how to do that, there must be a trick to do it but I could not find it.

```
SOAPMessage sm = null;
SOAPMessage response = null;

SOAPConnectionFactory sfc = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection connection = sfc.createConnection();

MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
sm = mf.createMessage();
...
...
URL url = new URL("https://server:XXXX/blablabla);
response = connection.call(sm, url);
```

I saw someone doing:

```
if (xxxSoapService instanceof Stub)
            ((Stub) xxxSoapService).setTimeout(10000);
```

xxxSoapService extends java.rmi.Remote and Stub is from import org.apache.axis.client.Stub;

There is probably something I am missing there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you're already doing your .call() in a background thread.  You can have a timer fire on a different thread and kill the loading thread.

Alternately, since SOAPMessage has all of your data you can just use HttpUrlConnection to send the message.

```
HttpUrlConnection connection = // initialize me!
connection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_VALUE);
SOAPMessage sm = // initialize me!

// more stuff for your message

connection.connect();

sm.writeTo(connection.getOutputStream());
```

This should work, unless I'm mistaken about the behavior of writeTo().

Comment: How could I get the answer back? Like before I was doing SOAPMessage response = connection.call(sm, server); I need to check the response for errors

Comment: Use connection.getInputStream().  That should give you the body of the response.  To get the headers there are a few methods: getHeaderField(), getHeaderFieldKey().  Check the HttpURLConnection documentation for more details.